# `enum` can only be set on an array of strings, not Mixed mongoose

Tags: mongoose

```
   this.schema = new Schema({
            telephoneNumber: {type: String, required: true},
            activationCode: {type: Number},
            timeOfCreationCode: {type: Number},
            stateOfActivationProcess: {type: Boolean},
            typeOfCar: {type: String},
            birthDay: {type: String},
            gender: {type: String},
            workingStatus: {type: Boolean},
            minDownPaymentAgreeOrNot: {type: Boolean},
            workingExperience: {type: String},
            monthlyIncome: {type: String},
            confirmMonthlyIncome: {type: Boolean},
            whyUserNeedCar: {
                type: Array,
                **enum : enumList,**
                require : true
            },
            userMonthlyBudget : {type : String}
        });
```

> Error: `enum` can only be set on an array of strings, not Mixed
>       at SchemaArray.enum (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:134:11)
>       at SchemaArray.SchemaType (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:55:18)
>       at new SchemaArray (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:85:14)
>       at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:580:12)
>       at Schema.path (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:460:29)
>       at Schema.add (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:341:12)
>       at new Schema (C:\carsapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:89:10)
>       at new UserDbCollection (C:\carsapp\models\user\user.js:9:23)
>       at Object. (C:\carsapp\models\user\user.js:62:28)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

Comment: [ask], [mcve]..

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) enums have to be used with Strings only, as the stack trace you showed to us says.

```
Error: enum can only be set on an array of strings
```

Look at the following example :

```
      drink: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Coffee', 'Tea'],
        required: function() {
          return this.bacon > 3;
        }
      }
```